# Update SQL column matching another column in the able with input as a list

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have table like this

```
Id   Name   Place
-----------------
 1    a
 2    b
 3    c
```

I need to write a stored procedure that accepts a list of both Id and Place as params and updates the place column based on matching Id.

Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a UDTT (User Defined Table Type) for this.

```
CREATE TYPE id_place AS TABLE (id INT, Place NVARCHAR(50));
```

Once you have one, you can add it as a stored procedure parameter. You can treat it like a table within the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTableName @inTable id_place READONLY
AS
BEGIN
 UPDATE T
   SET t.place = u.place
  FROM TableName t
    INNER JOIN @inTable u
      ON t.id = u.id;
END
```

Once you have the stored procedure all you need to do is execute it, passing the UDTT:

```
DECLARE @inTable id_place;
INSERT INTO @inTable (id, place) VALUES (1, 'New York'), (2, 'Las Vegas'),(3, 'Washington DC');

EXEC UpdateTableName @inTable;
```